# Don't escape HTML with docutils.core.publish_parts(writer_name="html")

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I'm trying to convert some of my HTML content to ReStructuredText. The problem is that I have a lot of custom HTML, so much that I'd abandon conversion if I had to write a special parser for each thing.

By default:

```
text = '''
  Heading
  =======
  <p class="jQuery-addThis">Test</p>
'''
docutils.core.publish_parts(text, writer_name='html')['html_body']
```

Escapes the `<`, `>`, and `"` with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&quot;`.

How do I tell `publish_parts` (or another function) to NOT convert the HTML?

Additional information:

I need this functionality for the following reasons:

- AddThis
- Google Analytics
- Discus
- Facebook Plugins
- Twitter Plugins

I've been told to switch to Markdown, but I'd rather use ReStructuredText. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I should've included "without the raw directive" in the subject line. I'm guessing that this is impossible, but if anyone knows of a way around it, I'd be very great full.

Comment: Also, I'd like to not do `output.replace('&lt;','<')` as I plan on using ReST's built-in \` and \`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`raw`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-directive) data pass-through directive. Your example would become:

```
text = '''
  Heading
  =======
  .. raw:: html

     <p class="jQuery-addThis">Test</p>
'''
docutils.core.publish_parts(text, writer_name='html')['html_body']
```

You can also look into using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to automatically convert the HTML to restructuredText.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of `.. raw:: html`, but I didn't want to use that method, since so much of the doc would contain extra lines plus the `raw` directive.

Comment: It's probably not an option for what you want to achieve, but I added a reference to _pandoc_ to my answer, in case it can be of any use.